# Define macros by using TikZ's \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

I would like to factorize a little the code below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\testabove[1]{above #1}
\newcommand\testbelow[1]{below #1}
\newcommand\testright[1]{right #1}
\newcommand\testleft[1]{left #1}

\begin{document}

\testabove{A} ;    
\testbelow{B} ;    
\testright{C} ;    
\testleft{D}

\end{document}
```

My idea is to use the `\foreach` loop of `tikz` but I am wrong with the following lines of codes. I am sure that I need to use `\expandafter` but any of my attempts has not worked.

Can I adapt the following lines such as to obtain my factorization ?

```
\foreach \kind in {above, below, right, left}{
    \newcommand\csname test\kind\endcsname[1]{\kind #1}
}
```

Using `\expandafter\gdef\csname test\kind\endcsname##1{kind ##1}` defines four macros, but not the right ones because I haven't use `{\kind ##1}`.

Indeed `\expandafter\gdef\csname test\kind\endcsname##1{\kind ##1}` gives the error message `Undefined control sequence \testabove #1->\kind`.

How can I make `\kind` be expanded in `{\kind ##1}` ?

Comment: Try doubling (or quadrupling or...) hashes...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I have updated my question by giving a less bad way to reach my goal at the ned of my question.

Comment: replace `\gdef` by `\xdef`

Comment: Great ! What is the difference ? `\gdef` for no argument and `\xdef` for arguments ?

Comment: @projetmbc Sorry, I saw your comment just now. `\gdef` is the same as `\global\def`. `\xdef` is the same as `\global\edef`. `\def` simply defines whatever is in the argument and `\edef` expands first, which is what you want. `\xdef` to have the definition be global.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification given to the very little LaTeX padawan I am. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do without Ti*k*Z, and, what may be more important, avoid making the macros global. You can use the built-in `\@for` macro instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@for\next:={above,below,right,left}\do{%
\expandafter\edef\csname test\next\endcsname#1{\next #1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\testabove{A}     
\testbelow{B}     
\testright{C} 
\testleft{D}
\end{document}
```

There are many ways in which you may generalize this and/or make it more user-friendly. I do not know what the ultimate purpose will be, but this is to give you some idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MultiDef}[3][]{\@for\next:=#3\do{%
\expandafter\edef\csname #2\next\endcsname##1{#1{\next} ##1}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\MultiDef{test}{above,below,right,left}
\testabove{A}     
\testbelow{B}     
\testright{C} 
\testleft{D}

\MultiDef[hibernate ]{pft}{above,below,right,left}
\pftabove{A}     
\pftbelow{B}     
\pftright{C} 
\pftleft{D}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. The meta programming is fully achieved with your `MultiDef` macro. I will keep it in my mind.

Comment: What are the drawbacks of making global a macro ?

Comment: @projetmbc In general you not want to do that. For instance, if you set in a `tikzpicture`, say, the `node distance` to `1cm`, this will apply to this `tikzpicture` only (or to the scope in which you set it). It will not affect the other `tikzpicture`s you have in your document. If it did, this would be a mess, you add a picture with some keys (keys *are* macros internally), and this will change every other picture. Similarly, if you set `\arraystretch` in one table, you do not want this to affect every other table. Therefore it is arguably better to keep many things local.

Comment: @projetmbc In this sample document, this does not really matter since you define these things on the "outermost level". But it *might* matter if you accidentally overwrite existing macros. Again, if you only use these redefinitions locally, you may not break some stuff using the original definitions somewhere else.

Comment: Very clear comments. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6):

The `\foreach` function is meant for repetitive actions in Ti*k*Z pictures and has several drawbacks when employed elsewhere, the main one being that every cycle is performed in a group.

Here's a more general way to accomplish your needs; the defined macros can have as many arguments as you like (from none to nine, of course). In the fourth argument (the template) you denote by `#1` the current item in the cycle and by `##1`, `##2` and so on the defined macro arguments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\batchdefine}{mO{0}mm}
 {% #1 is the prefix
  % #2 (default 0) is the number of arguments
  % #3 is a comma separated list
  % #4 is the template
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 } 
   {
    \projetmbc_batchdefine:cnn { #1 ##1 } { #2 } { #4 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_batchdefine:Nnn
 {
  \newcommand{#1}[#2]{#3}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \projetmbc_batchdefine:Nnn { c }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\batchdefine{test}[1]{
  above, below, right, left
}{#1 ##1}

\batchdefine{TEST}[2]{
  above, below, right, left
}{##1 #1 ##2}

\begin{document}

\testabove{a} \testbelow{b} \testright{r} \testleft{l}

\TESTabove{a}{A} \TESTbelow{b}{B} \TESTright{r}{R} \TESTleft{l}{L}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One day I will learn the power LaTeX4-3 coding... One day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments of Phelype Oleinik and LaTeXer, the following solution has been build.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\foreach \kind in {above,below,right,left}{
    \expandafter\xdef\csname test\kind\endcsname##1{\kind ##1}
}


\begin{document}

\testabove{A} ;    
\testbelow{B} ;    
\testright{C} ;    
\testleft{D}

\end{document}
```